# How to aggregate only neighbour records in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, aggregation

Let us suppose I have a table called locations, it contains records for a source's position and when this position was recorded.

| id | source_id | ts | position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3134 | 2021-02-21 20:48:08.488359 | ... |
| 2 | 3134 | 2021-02-21 20:48:09.123422 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

ts is short for timestamp and the position is in postgis format but it doesn't really matter for this question.

And I have another table called zones:

| id | area |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ... |
| 2 | ... |
| ... | ... |

The area is a polygon in postgis format.

I can test if a point is in an area for example

```
SELECT locations.source_id, zones.id, locations.ts
from locations inner join
     zones
     on ST_Contains(zones.area, locations.position);
```

will tell me which source is in which zone when.

What I would like is a query which produces the following output:

| locations.source_id | zones.id | in_zone_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3134 | 1 | 1 mins |
| 3134 | 2 | 4 mins |
| 3134 | 1 | 2 mins |
| ... | ... | ... |

So it will tell me that the source 3134 was in zone 1 for 1 minute, after that it was in zone 2 for 4 minutes and then it was in zone 1 again for 2 minutes.

How do I achieve aggregation in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a flag and then treat this as a gaps-and-islands problem.  It is not clear how `time` is calculated, but the idea is:

```
select source_id, id, min(ts), max(ts), max(ts) - min(ts) as diff
from (select l.source_id, z.id, l.ts,
             row_number() over (partition by l.source_id order by l.ts) as seqnumm
             row_number() over (partition by l.source_id, z.id order by l.ts) as seqnum_2
      from locations l inner join
           zones
           on ST_Contains(z.area, l.position)
     ) lz
group by (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

This makes a few assumptions:

- All points are in a zone.  Or at least, you only care about the points within a zone.
- Poinsts are only in one zone at a time.
- The time spent in a zone is the difference between the earliest and last records of being in the zone.

All of these are a quite reasonable interpretation of your question, but can be relaxed.  If your requirements are different, I would suggest that you ask a *new* question, being explicit about the details of the problem.  Sample data and corresponding desired results are very helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much :) This was almost exactly what I wanted, but I was able to modify it to suit my needs. Thanks for being awesome :)